# MySQL - Constraint NOT NULL Error 1064

Tags: mysql, constraints, notnull

i want to create a table and i get an error :
[image: My Errorcode]

Why doesn't he like my constraint? is mysql so different to sql? because 2 years ago i created the same table with no problems in sql :(

here the whole code

```
CREATE table Mitarbeiter(
Mitarbeiternummer INT(5),
Personennummer INT(5) constraint not_null_mitarbpersnr NOT NULL,
Gehalt INT(10),
Chef_Mitarbeiternummer INT(5),
constraint mitarbeiter_pk primary key (Mitarbeiternummer),
constraint unique_mitpernr UNIQUE (Personennummer),
constraint marb_fk_persnr foreign key(Personennummer) references person(Personennummer) ON DELETE CASCADE,
constraint marb_fk_chef foreign key (Chef_Mitarbeiternummer) references mitarbeiter(Mitarbeiternummer));
```

Also i get the same error when i want to write "personennummer NUMBER(5)"
but it is a personal identification number and so every personennummer has the same lenght 5 for instance the first has '00001' and so on

I hope you can answer my questions :)

Comment: show the actual sql causing this.

Comment: why do you want to give that constraint a name?

Comment: actual sql is now in the post

i've learned this at the university - so i can change it afterwards i think? :/

Comment: will you? ever? really?

Comment: no but it's for a project at the university and i think my professor think i will - maybe :P but is that the problem?

Comment: There are two types of people. Programmers, and people who are afraid to experiment with things...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Other databases, such as Oracle, do assign a name to `NOT NULL` constraints. If a name is not supplied, Oracle assigns a system generated name like `SYS_nnnnnn`. And some developers/DBAs have a preference for having a consistent name for the constraint, rather than a system generated name that is different in each environment (dev, test, qa, pre-prod, production.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support syntax to give a name to a `NOT NULL` constraint.

This will throw an error:

```
  Personennummer INT(5) constraint not_null_mitarbpersnr NOT NULL
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To declare a `NOT NULL` constraint on a column in MySQL, you have to omit the keyword `CONSTRAINT` and the name. This syntax is valid:

```
  Personennummer INT(5) NOT NULL
```

---

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Note that the syntax following `CONSTRAINT` does not allow `NOT NULL`.  The `NOT NULL` is included as part of the column definition.

MySQL differs from other databases, such as Oracle, which *do* allow you to give a name to a `NOT NULL` constraint. I Oracle, I think the NOT NULL constraint shows up as a constraint in the dictionary. So it's understandable that we'd want to give a specific name, rather than having a system generated `SYS_nnnnnn` name assigned. In MySQL, `NOT NULL` is handled as an attribute of the column, not as a separate constraint.